# Is it correct to say: "Last year we had an exhibition that showcase how the town square has changed over the past fifty years."

Tags: transcription

I heard a sentence as followed

> Last year we had an exhibition that showcase how the town square has changed over the past fifty years.

Is it correct?

https://liuxue.koolearn.com/toefl/listen/619-2055-q0.html

around 47 second

the sound of / -d / (in particular / -t /) is quite weak.

I thought in the context the word ‘**showcased**’ should be used instead of ‘**showcase**’.

Some websites which show incorrect transcript distract me.

http://www.moguedu.com/toefl/info/2385/53.html

Are there any other better explanation?

Comment: Please mention where you heard it.  I'd assume it was a simple mistake.

Comment: @JamesK  I just add the source. Is it just because the sound of / -d / is soft and weak. Why is that?

Comment: She says "showcased"  It isn't very clear, but the "t" sound (is unvoiced) is heard  and it is written as "showcased" in the transcript.

Comment: And some other websites do not write "showcased" in their transcripts, instead just "showcase". It is a part of test preparation of TOEFL. That is why I am not sure and ask. Thanks for your confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct choice is "showcased" rather than "showcase".

- the transcript says "showcase*d*".
- the woman says "showcase*d*".
- the word expected by a fluent listener is "showcase*d*".

It doesn't sound like any error was made.

During speaking, many syllables will not be *emphasized*. So, they pass by very quickly, almost inaudibly. It may depend on the listener expecting to hear something, and then the smallest indication of the sound is enough to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

The "ed" /t/ sound in "showcased" is actually elided. That is why you don't hear it. Why is it elided?

The "ed" /t/ sound here is commonly referred to as ***dropped t*** or ***silent t*** because the "ed" /t/ or t sound is a middle consonant sound between words.

Please look at [the film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CojrvLQXybA) at 1:08 around. You will find how the teacher utters "just thinking" without pronouncing t. If you need the detailed rules of ***dropped t/silent t***, you can google them.

Comment: Great! These directions you gave are tips to get clear ideas on this topic. Appreciate it.